# Yii2 Active record query multiple where clause from array

Tags: yii2

Yii2's index page's default data provider is like following:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => ModelName::find(),
]);
```

Now, I've got an array like `$arr = [1, 2, 4, 6];`

I want to add a where clause like:

```
WHERE parentId=1 OR parentId=2 OR parentId=4 OR parentId=6
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Can be done like this:

```
$query = ModelName::find()->where(['parentId' => $arr]);

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);
```

When you pass an array to `where`, Yii automatically transforms it into `IN` condition.

So generated SQL conditional part will be `WHERE parentId IN (1, 2, 4, 6);`.

It's equivalent to your mentioned condition with `OR`.